# Replacing Text which does not match a pattern in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have below text in a CLOB in a table 

Table Name: tbl1
Columns
col1 - number (Primary Key)
col2 - clob (as below)

Row#1
-----
Col1 = 1
Col2 =
1331882981,ab123456,Some text here
which can run multiple lines and have a lot of text...
~1331890329,pqr123223,Some more text...

Row#2
-----
Col1 = 2
Col2 =
1331882981,abc333,Some text here
which can run multiple lines and have a lot of text...
~1331890329,pqrs23,Some more text...


Now I need to know how we can get below output

Col1    Value
----    ---------------------
1       1331882981,ab123456
1       1331890329,pqr123223
2       1331882981,abc333
2       1331890329,pqrs23

([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+.), ==> This is the regular expression to match "1331890329,pqrs23" and I need to know how can replace which are not matching this regex and then split them into multiple rows

**EDIT#1**
I am on Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 and hence cannot use REGEXP_COUNT function :-( Also, the col2 is a CLOB which is massive

**EDIT#2**
I've tried below query and it works fine for some records (i.e. if I add a "where" clause). But when I remove the "where", it never returns any result. I've tried to put this into a view and insert into a table and left it run overnight but still it had not completed :(

```
with t as (select col1, col2 from temp_table)
select col1,
       cast(substr(regexp_substr(col2, '[^~]+', 1, level), 1, 50) as
            varchar2(50)) data
  from t
connect by level <= length(col2) - length(replace(col2, '~')) + 1
```

**EDIT#3**

```
# of Chars in Clob      Total
-----------             -----
0 - 1k                  3196
1k - 5k                 2865
5k - 25k                 661
25k - 100k                36
> 100k                     2
-----------             -----
Grand Total             6760
```

I have ~7k rows of clobs which have the distribution as shown above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solutions didn't work and below is what I did.

```
update temp_table set col2=regexp_replace(col2,'([0-9]{10},[a-z0-9]+)','(\1)') ;
update temp_table set col2=regexp_replace(col2,'\),[\s\S]*~\(','(\1)$');
update temp_table set col2=regexp_replace(col2,'\).*?\(','$');
update temp_table set col2=replace(regexp_replace(col2,'\).*',''),'(','');
```

After these 4 update commands, the col2 will have something like

```
1 1331882981,ab123456$1331890329,pqr123223
2 1331882981,abc333$1331890329,pqrs23
```

Then I wrote a function to split this thing. The reason I went for the function is to split by "$" and the fact that the col2 still has >10k characters

```
create or replace function parse( p_clob in clob ) return sys.odciVarchar2List
pipelined
as
        l_offset number := 1;
        l_clob   clob := translate( p_clob, chr(13)|| chr(10) || chr(9), '   ' ) || '$';
        l_hit    number;
begin
        loop
          --Find occurance of "$" from l_offset
          l_hit := instr( l_clob, '$', l_offset );
          exit when nvl(l_hit,0) = 0;
          --Extract string from l_offset to l_hit
          pipe row ( substr(l_clob, l_offset , (l_hit - l_offset)) );
          --Move offset
          l_offset := l_hit+1;
        end loop;
end;
```

I then called

```
select col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_value, '[^,]+', 1, 1) col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_value, '[^,]+', 1, 2) col4
  from temp_table, table(parse(temp_table.col2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like:

```
with v as
(
  select 1 col1, '1331882981,ab123456,Some text here
which can run multiple lines and have a lot of text...
~1331890329,pqr123223,Some more text...' col2 from dual
  union all
  select 2 col1, '133188298777,abc333,Some text here
which can run multiple lines and have a lot of text...
~1331890329,pqrs23,Some more text...' col2 from dual
)
select distinct col1, regexp_substr(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', 1, level) split
from v
connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z0-9]+)')
order by col1
;
```

This gives:

```
1   1331882981,ab123456
1   1331890329,pqr123223
2   1331890329,pqrs23
2   3188298777,abc333
```

**EDIT :** for 10g, `REGEXP_COUNT` does not exist but you have [workarounds](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12818.html). Here I replace the pattern found by something I hope I won't find in the text (here, `XYZXYZ` but you can choose something much more complex to be confident), do a diff with the same matching but replaced by the empty string, then divide by my pattern length (here, `6`):

```
with v as
(
  select 1 col1, '1331882981,ab123456,Some text here
which can run multiple lines and have a lot of text...
~1331890329,pqr123223,Some more text...' col2 from dual
  union all
  select 2 col1, '133188298777,abc333,Some text here
which can run multiple lines and have a lot of text...
~1331890329,pqrs23,Some more text...' col2 from dual
)
select distinct col1, regexp_substr(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', 1, level) split
from v
connect by level <= (length(REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', 'XYZXYZ')) - length(REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', ''))) / 6
order by col1
;
```

**EDIT 2 :** CLOBs (and LOBs in general) and regexp don't seem to fit well together:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Converting the CLOG to a string (`regexp_substr(to_char(col2), ...`) seems to fix the issue.

**EDIT 3 :** CLOBs don't like `distinct` either, so converting split result to char in an embedded request and then using the `distinct` on the upper request succeeds !

```
select distinct col1, split from
(
    select col1, to_char(regexp_substr(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', 1, level)) split
    from temp_epn
    connect by level <= (length(REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', 'XYZXYZ')) - length(REGEXP_REPLACE(col2, '([0-9]{10},[a-z 0-9]+)', ''))) / 6
    order by col1
);
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. I tried that but am getting below error. ORA-00904: "REGEXP_COUNT": invalid identifier

I am on Oracle 10.2.0.5.0

Comment: Have a look at my edit, it should give you a nice workaround.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, this gave an error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB` when I changed the "with" to `with t as (select col1, col2 from temp_table)` (col2 has clob)

Comment: I simulated the same table with a CLOB, use `to_char` as in my last edit to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. This works only for CLOBs which have <4000 characters. For large ones, it throws this error: `ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 303627, maximum: 4000)`

Comment: I think I have it now, at least !

Comment: Still no luck, this simply keeps executing in PL/SQL and never comes back. I've found a way to address this myself (please see the answer). Thanks for your help !

Comment: Upvote, extracting patterns from clob with
`with v as
(
select id, DBMS_LOB.substr(content,20000) content from sometable
)
select id, regexp_substr(content, '([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7})', 1, level) split
from v
connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT(content, '([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7})')
;`